# How to remove zeros at starting

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[**Plunker**.](http://jsfiddle.net/hcyj3q6q/572/)

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.abc', function(e){ 
       if (this.selectionStart == 0 && (e.which == 48 || e.which == 46) ){
          return false;
       }
    });
```

In the above plunker it is restricting zero's when I try to enter. But when I go with cursor and remove the values before zero, then the zero's are remains.. but I don't want to show zeros before value...

Comment: SO isn't a "how to" site. You're supposed to do research. Tons of it. Once you have found a way to do this after learning about all the available tools, and you have tried implementing a solution and failed for days, then you can post here and ask for help by adding a [mcve] to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```js
var yourString = "00001";
yourString = Number(yourString).toString();
```